# Convert inputstream byte to character

Tags: java

I have text with contents

```
12       13        14
```

The text has 8 spaces between values 12 and 13 and 13 and 14

My java method is receiving the text as inputstream thru an argument and storing each contents in a byte array, and further then convert each byte to a character

```
public class FileUpload implements RequestStreamHandler{

String fileObjKeyName = "sample1.txt";
String bucketName="";

/**
 * @param args
 */
 @Override
 public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {

        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[ ");
        sb1.append("[ ");
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            sb.append(b);
            char ch = (char) b;
           sb1.append(ch);

        }
        sb.append("]");
        sb1.append("] ");

        logger.log(sb.toString());
        logger.log(sb1.toString()); 

  }
}
```

The Decimal representation for the each bytes are correctly printed as below

```
[ 4950323232323232323249513232323232323232324952]
```

However when converted to character, only one decimal value '32' (for spaces) between the values are getting converted, skipping all remaining in between spaces bytes.

```
[ 12 13 14]
```

Can anyone suggest, the reason for this.

Comment: Very doubtful. Rather, it's much more likely that whatever you're using to display your output, purposely collapses consecutive spaces into only one, in exactly the same way as you could see that StackOverflow does unless told otherwise. But let's prove it. Please post a complete example, so that we can copy/paste your code and run it and see what it does, without any modification whatsoever.

Comment: how u convert bytes to array. give your code

Comment: see below complete code @Sumeendar

Comment: Yes - @Sumeendar

Comment: Can't say for sure, but it looks like that you're rendering the output as html. Try outputting `<b>bold</b>`.

Answer (score 1):

How you convert byte to string? it will be same. see below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] bytes = "12        13        14".getBytes();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
    String str = new String(bytes,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows that you're using AWS, for which you will often check the results and the produced logs online, with a tool that supports HTML.

And in HTML, when you write several consecutive spaces, they are displayed as only one.

Your String object, withing Java, does contain the 8 spaces. But when you give it to a logger to be eventually displayed in a webpage, the spaces are collapsed and displayed as only one.

This is easy to prove: just add the following code at the end of your method:

```
String s = sb1.toString();
logger.log("s length: " + s.length());
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  logger.log("s[" + i + "]: " + s.charAt(i));
}
```

It demonstrates the length and exact content of the String. If you're not seeing that exact content when displaying the String, it is the fault of the tool that displays it.